# Api Instagram, get New comments of any media (since parameter date or id)

Tags: instagram-api

How can I get recent comments in my media files from a date or id?

That is, I am interested in getting all the comments of any media file that have been published since a date or a comment id that I already have.

From what I've seen I should go through each media and go through all the comments it contains to find the new ones.

But this way does not seem right to me since I would have to make many calls going through the media and its comments again and again until I find a new one.

I have also seen that the subscriptions are not yet active for the media or comments, which would be great because it is what I seek to get the new comments, instead of having to go all the way through the same in search of some new.

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no API currently to automatically get new comments from a bunch of media.

You have to get new comments from single media and compare manually for dates with code using this API:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/{media-id}/comments?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

Also note that this API only returns the latest 150 comments, so if the media is very popular and gets more that 150 comments, you have to time the API call at regular intervals and check dates so you dont miss out on some new comments

Comment: Thanks krisrak, It's what I thought. I will have to control the rate on the requests so as not to exceed it. But in accounts with a lot of traffic it is a pity not to have a more efficient method to always get the latest comments.